# Delete when no other rows are using a relationship?

Tags: mysql

I have a users table and an images table.

A user has only one image.

An image can belong to many users.

I'm trying to make it so that when a user is deleted, it's image is deleted but only if no other users are using that image.

I've tried to use on delete cascade but it only works the opposite way to what I'm trying to achieve - when you delete an image, the user is deleted.

```
Users:
id | name | image_id

Images:
id | url
```

Comment: You cannot do this with a delete cascade. If you think you will have performance issues doing a periodic sweep to tidy up images you might want to write a delete trigger on users to capture the images which are candidates for deletion and use this to test if they can actually be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the not used  image with

```
  select  i.id, i.url  
  from  images i 
  left join  users u  on u.image_id = i.id
  where  image_id is null
```

and delete

```
delete  i.* 
from  images i  
inner join  (

      select  i.id
      from  images i 
      left join  users u  on u.image_id = i.id
      where  image_id is null 
) t on t.id  = i.id
```

if you have issue related  to the fact that you are delete row that are involved in select then

```
delete  i.* 
from  images i  
inner join  ( 
  select  id 
  from ( 

      select  i.id
      from  images i 
      left join  users u  on u.image_id = i.id
      where  image_id is null  
  ) t1 
) t on t.id  = i.id
```

Comment: So no way to do this with cascade delete?

Comment: the constrains for cascade delete  should be from master to detail   in your case you have   not this situation  but you want delete the detail only when is the last detail  ..  and  (for what i know)  there is not this kind o constrains in mysql  .. if you don't want a perdiodical function for delete .. you could use a trigger  that for each delete perform the check  ..

Answer (score 0):

If you can do this cleanup with a separate query, this will work

```
   DELETE FROM Images WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT image_id FROM Users);
```

Comment: So no way to do this with cascade delete?